# Journald and Sources of Log Messages

Tags: logs, timestamps, rsyslog, syslog, messaging

I would like to know what process is meant to write Timestapms (and other parts of Log messages) in `Syslog` protocol.
In other words, is it `Syslog` that sets timestamp of log message (exact time of message beiing received) or the process that sends the message (exact time of message beiing sent)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`journald` itself timestamps log messages. It's actually a security issue as well - allowing daemons/services to supply time stamps could result in bogus/false data.